# Angular2 relative template path and module format

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In Angular 2, to support templates with a **relative** path, you have to set 
`moduleId: module.id` inside the component decorator. (see [here](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/))

The "problem" is it requires compiling the project in commonjs format.
How should you do it with other modules format ? (like systemjs)

Comment: Found 2 links that seem to indicate it's not yet possible : 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6131

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate: [Using relative path for templateUrl in Angular2 Component with SystemJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556154/using-relative-path-for-templateurl-in-angular2-component-with-systemjs)

Anyway, in a nutshell:

SystemJS supports CommonJS, so you can just set it to commonjs. However
module.id, is not recognized by TypeScript, but it does exist. so you need to add a declaration file:

tsconfig.json

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

typings.d.ts

```
declare var module: { id: string };
```

It might be a good idea to take a close look at how angular-cli generates projects.