# Differences of using Component template vs templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular 2 allows to write multi-line templates by using ` characters to enquote them. It is also possible to put multi-line template into `.html` file and reference it by `templateUrl`.

It seems comfortable for me to put the template directly into component as then it's all in one place, but is there any drawback of doing so?

1st approach:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 multiline template</h1>
    <p>Second line</p> 
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

vs 
2nd approach:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'multi-line.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

together with `multi-line.html`:

```
<h1>My First Angular 2 multiline template</h1>
<p>Second line</p>
```

Comment: **Template Strings** using **backticks** are part of ecmascript 6 specification, not angular. So you need to have a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: IMHO,as a React user , I prefer inline templates and inline styles

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In terms of how the final application will perform, there's no real difference between having an embedded template and an external template.

For the developer, however, there are a number of differences that you have to consider.

1. You get better code completion and inline support in your editor/IDE in most cases when the HTML is in a separate `.html` file.  (IntelliJ IDEA, at least, supports HTML for inline templates and strings)
2. There is a convenience factor to having code and the associated HTML in the same file. It's easier to see how the two relate to each other.

These two things will be of equal value for many people, so you'd just pick your favorite and move ahead with life if this were all there was to it.

But that leads us to the reasons you should keep your templates in your components, in my opinion:

3. It is difficult to make [use of relative filepaths for external templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557780/1480995) as it currently stands in Angular 2.
4. Using non-relative paths for external templates makes your components far less portable, since you need to manage all of the `/where/is/my/template` type references from the root that change depending on how deep your component is.

That's why I would suggest that you keep your templates inside your components where they are easily found.  Also, if you find that your inline template is getting large and unwieldy, then it is probably a sign that you should be breaking your component down into several smaller components, anyway.

Comment: I have been writing html views separately in development, but then using gulp-angular-embed-templates to embed the html into the component for production

Comment: You can place templates in separate files and still use the ```template``` property by importing your template as a string. The component is no longer bound by the location of its template and can be used from anywhere. ```import myTemplate from 'app/dashboard.html'; @Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    template: myTemplate })```

Comment: @ You can use `const template = require(./template.html)` instead of `import` in cjs. In type script 2.0 you'll be able to do this without losing type safety

Comment: I recently moved some small HTML templates inside my `.ts` files for easier maintenance and avoid HTTP request overhead, and also avoid issues with  require js.

Comment: I can't even imagine trying to write a template inline inside the .ts file. Maybe 20 years ago if I was using `vi` but the only place I would ever do it today is if the template was fewer than 5 lines or it was a plunkr.

Answer (score 18):

The drawbacks are that the IDE tooling isn't as strong as mentioned above, and putting large chunks of html into your components makes them harder to read.

Also, if you are following the angular2 style guide, it recommends that you ***do*** extract templates into a separate file when longer than 3 lines.

From the angular2 style guide :

> **Do** extract templates and styles into a separate file, when more than 3
> lines.
>
> **Why?** Syntax hints for inline templates in (.js and .ts) code files are
> not supported by some editors.
>
> **Why?** A component file's logic is easier to read when not mixed with
> inline template and styles.

[Source](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#05-04)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a string literal to `template` consisting of your components HTML. This way you have the HTML source in the same file as the TypeScript code.

With `templateUrl` you're referencing an external file containing the template HTML. This way you have HTML and TypeScript in separate files.

In an external file you usually have better support for auto-completion and syntax check, but can be cumbersome because every component consists of several files instead of one (there are also styles). External files need to be inlined in a build step, otherwise you'd have lots of server requests for loading all the template files.

The Angular2 style guide suggests to not have inline templates with more than 3 lines.

Comment: Is there any advantage or drawback to keep template in external file or in string literal?

Comment: In an external file you usually have better support for auto-completion and syntax check, but can be cumbersome because every component consitsts of several files instead of one (there are also styles). External files need to be inlined in a build step, otherwise you'd have lots of server requests for loading all the template files.

Answer (score 2):

One of the drawbacks of putting your template HTML into separate file might happen if you're developing Angular2+ **library** that supposed to be used in other projects.

In this case the consumers of your library **might not be able to perform JIT compilation** successfully unless they use template loaders like [angular2-template-loader](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader) or [angular2-rollup](https://github.com/steveblue/angular2-rollup) or any other depending on the bundler that should be properly configured that sometimes might be tricky.

To avoid this drawback and still have templates in separate files (which i think is quite convenient) the library developer might end up **inlining templates automatically** using Gulp plugin like **gulp-inline-ng2-template** or any other. But this would mean additional level of complexity while building ES2015 version of the library.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers seam to be around editor support, but, while that argument is true, I would not argue that as a strong point for putting the html and css into .html and .css files.

The main reason that I separate my html and css files is because it follows [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It allows for easy code portability and reuse as Angular changes versions and syntax of how the typescript should be layed out, your html and css stay for the most part the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working now.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
```

Taken from 'tour of heros' https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html and adapted to test this concrete issue.

angular2@2.0.0-beta.8

Comment: I still fail to get this to work, and I'm running Beta 16.  Where do you have your `.html` and `.css` files? Are they in the same folder as your my-dashboard component's `.ts` file?

Comment: **important**: @see [component-relative-paths]:(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

The only location Angular can be sure of is the URL of the ```index.html```
home page, **the application root**. So by default it resolves template
and style paths relative to the URL of index.html. That's why we
previously wrote our file URLs with an app/ base path prefix.

*[snip]*
That knowledge enables us to tell Angular where the component file is
by setting the moduleId:
  
 ```moduleId: module.id,```