# What is the difference between app.component.ts & app.component.html

Tags: angular

I am not understanding the difference between `app.component.ts` & `app.component.html` in `angular 2`.

I am able to create the page using both. Then what to use in developing a web page.

Please guide me, I am new to angularjs2.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't what you are trying to ask. But if you are asking difference between `template`/`templateUrl`, then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673979/what-are-differences-of-using-component-template-vs-templateurl-in-angular2-type

Comment: Exactly what i want to ask.Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts - This file is main class file for any component
app.component.html - This file is component's html which can be bind with app component

app.component.ts has one @component decorator in which you can also define your html part as template

if you want to give any html file external link then you will use templateUrl and pass html file into it

Answer (score 0):

Difference between app.component.ts and app.component.html is that the HTML content rendered is from app.component.html and the logics written for data manipulation are done in app.component.ts.

All your functions are written in .ts file and html elements goes in .html file.

However you may not need the HTML file all the time, in some case the HTML to be rendered might be very less and static like below

```
   <p>Welcome to my page</p>
```

If this the case you don't need a separate .html file you can just use

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-selector',
     template: '<p>Welcome to my page</p>',   
     styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss']
   )}
```

Having a separate file for writing your function logics and rendering html elements will help in debugging and many such things. It'll improve the legibility.