# Angular 5 templateUrl ignored via Webpack

Tags: html, angular, webpack

So I have two projects, the first is a utilities project containing reusable assets including custom services and Angular components. The second is a client projoect that will consume this utilities project via node_modules.

I am currently using Angular 5.1.1 and Webpack 3.10.0 to build via AOT and bundle via Webpack into a single file called bundle.js

The utilities project is built as a commonjs build and ngc (aot) 5.1.1, so the output of the utilities project is a reusable aot module. The problem is with the client and its resulting bundle.js file. The utilties project contains Angular components that use templateUrl/styleUrls and relative paths to both the html and css file per component. When I build the Client (Which utilises the built version of this utilities via node_modules), webpack simply does not have reference to the html parts of the utilities project per component and hence it is missing from the bundle.js

Webpack does successfully import the utiltities module and services but the templateUrl and StyleUrl are left untouched. Hence when I boot into a browser the files that it complains about are the html file that recide within the utilities (node_modules)

My webpack is below...

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: "bundle.js.map",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {

        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

A snippet from my bundle.js, MyComponent is within the utilities project provided as part of node_modules, notice the problem with the Urls

```js
MyComponent.decorators = [
 { type: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["n" /* Component */], args: [{
    moduleId: module.i.toString(),
    selector: "my-component",
    styleUrls: ["my-component.css"],
    templateUrl: "my-component.html",
    animations: [
     __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__core_my_animation_module__["a" /* MyAnimationModule */].scaleHeight("scaleHeight", "175ms"),
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__directives_my_selectable_item_directive__["a" /* MySelectableItemDirective */], useExisting: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["_19" /* forwardRef */])(function () { return MyComponent; }) }],
   },] },
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved it using `'template'` instead of `'templateUrl'` in `@Component`.
Refer to [What are differences of using Component template vs templateUrl in Angular2 Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673979/what-are-differences-of-using-component-template-vs-templateurl-in-angular2-type)

Comment: I think the question was to use angular2-template-loader and load template from using `templateURL`. The angular2-template-loader claims it can load templates from URL by the method explain in below link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-template-loader#how-does-it-work

Comment: @akashpandey angular2-template-loader does not work with webpack 5 and is 6 years dead! https://dev.to/antjanus/switching-from-angular2-template-loader-to-ngtools-webpack-117g  This offers a way to migrate to webpack 5 by using @ngtools/webpack, but not sure if it's really that simple