# Angular 7: What is "template" inside the @Component decorator?

Tags: angular

What is the use of "template" inside the @Component decorator? I do know how "templateURL" works but I haven't tried writing HTML inside of a component.

[image]

What is the advantages of using this instead of templateURLs? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences of using Component template vs templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673979/differences-of-using-component-template-vs-templateurl)

Comment: why don't you read up on https://angular.io/api/core/Component instead of asking such questions here. Try google first.

Comment: none, other that is can be in the same file. If your template is 1 line long, some might consider it an overkill to create a separate file. I have also seen projects only using template, and no file splitting. Please avoid this if your template is long.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use template you can write your html in your .ts file. If you have a small component (3 lines is the default in most tslint examples) this can be useful to reduce the clutter of seperate .html files.

But if you are making a bigger component you should keep using templateUrl to improve readability and to keep the view and the logic seperated.

You can put everything in template, but is not recommended in the official Angular style guide. [Style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#extract-templates-and-styles-to-their-own-files)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Seems like this is a useful information for my future use cases to use either template or templateURLs  on different kinds of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not particularly linked to Angular 7. `template` and `templateUlr` have been introduced since Angular 2.

There are actually several questions in your question. Let's dive in!

- `template` is for writing your pseudo HTML document inside of the `ts` file.
- `templateUrl` is for referencing an external file that contains your pseudo HTML

There is no consequence for production management, because your project is (hopefuly) going to be converted in a static web site where everything is optimized and minified.

So it really boils down to what is easier for you to read and manage.

Comment: I personnaly prefer `templateUrl` rather than `template`, even for small files. It enforces consistency throughout your projects.

Comment: Glad to know the deeper information of practical uses of it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I voted your question up. I'm sorry you have got so many downs. But I guess this is the way you have to learn.

Comment: I really recommand you to do the Angular tutorial. It is super informative!