# Angular2 relative paths for templateUrl and styleUrls?

Tags: view, angular, relative-path

While searching I found something named as `moduleId` to set the relative paths of template and CSS files, but I don't know exactly how to use `moduleId` in our components of angular2?

Actually, the problem is in my folder structure.I am loading my all .js files from `dist` folder whereas my view(.html files) are in the `src` folder. So when I use `moduleId: module.id` like this angular took the path from `dist` folder, instead of src folder.

So anybody here helps me tell that How to set custom moduleId for my component angualr2?

My folder structure like this.

```
                                  App
                                  /\
                                 /  \
             (.js + .map files)Dist    Src(.ts + .html + .css files)
```

- Folder Dist containes all .map and .js files
- Folder src containes all .ts, .HTML, and .css file.

Actual coding (working) -

```
@Component({
    selector: 'class-timing',
    templateUrl: 'src/components/TimeTable/class-timing/class-timing.html',
    styleUrls: ['src/app.css']
})
```

Modified coding (Not working due to incorrect path) -

```
@Component({
    selector: 'class-timing',
    templateUrl: 'class-timing.html',
    moduleId: module.id,
    styleUrls: ['src/app.css']
})
```

Referring to this tutorial
http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/

Comment: Seems related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556154/using-relative-path-for-templateurl-in-angular2-component-with-systemjs, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2383#issuecomment-176461396

Comment: yups related to, but not exact what i want, have you any idea about this question ?

Comment: No, I don't use TS myself, only for Plunkers ;-)

Comment: @PardeepJain, You can use angular-cli, They provide auto-setup for this all. Very easy to use

Comment: yeah i know but i would prefer setup settled by myself, angular-cli best for fresher's i think, you can see my setup here https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved my Problem by changing path (from `src` to `dist`)of importing file at the run time like this :-

```
moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/src/")
```

By doing so you can change path directory of module ID.

thanks to @Nicolai for this [awesome comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35499937/5043867)

PS:- Posting as answer may help someone

Answer (score 1):

I also had some questions about what worked and didn't work for TemplateUrl paths. I found the following was true in my testing:

templateUrl: 'folder name / file name' did not work

templateUrl: '/folder name / file name' did not work

templateUrl: './folder name / file name' DID work

so you might try that out.

Comment: does't work, already tried, btw whats the difference between these three ?

Comment: Here is a good explanation of relative (starts with /, ./ or ../) vs non-relative paths in typescript and how they are resolved https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html