# Angular 2 component .html path

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I try to use relative paths for html in component also i am mapping my js files in dist folder.. my component code is

app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

the html file is in same directory i.e
app/app.component.html

```
<h1> Wolaa </h1>
```

I am getting following error

[image: Error i get]

***Its totally clear that angular is finding app.component.html file at "dist/app/app.component.html" which is not there how can i fix this??***

My systemjs.config.js file is

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'dist', //'app',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

and my tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some details about template relative paths in the documentation that may help:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a "./" before your relative path like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: This is not the solution. The problem remains since `dist` directory is not containing hrml and css files. They need to be copied to `dist` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that I could find so far:
`moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/src/");` where `src` in my case is `app`.
Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451917/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls).

Comment: It sure is :( Probably moving to webpack will obviate this. I'll try that in the near future. But hey, it works and it's still one liner :)